# What does the cursive O with the subscript (n_y) mean in the following paper?

Tags: notation, markov-chains, linear-programming

The paper [Markov Data-Based Control](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245373271_Markov_data-based_LQG_control), at equation (3.11), on the 5th page of the pdf (page 554), top of the right column, shows the following expression for G:

> $\textbf{G}_k=-(R+\textbf{B}^T_{k+1}(\textbf{Q}^{-1}_{k+1}+\textbf{S}_{k+1}RS_{k+1}^T)^{-1}\textbf{B}_{k+1})^{-1}\textbf{B}^T_{k+1} \cdot (\textbf{Q}^{-1}_{k+1}+\textbf{S}_{k+1}\textbf{R}^{-1}_{k+1}\textbf{S}^T_{k+1})^{-1}[O_{n_y} \ \ \textbf{I}_{(N-k)n_y}]$

what is $O_{n_y}$?

Moreover, I believe that $RS_{k+1}^T$ should be in bold, and the first $R$ should be $\textbf{R}_{k+1}$ as R is just a covariance matrix and the bolded R ($\textbf{R}$) is defined below the expression on the paper as $\textbf{R}_{k+1}=diag(R, R, ...R)$. Does this mean that $R$ changes too and in reality it should be read as $\textbf{R}_{k+1}=diag(R_1, R_2, ...R_{k+1})$?

Comment: Could it mean a $n_y\times n_y$ zero matrix?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I thought that too but then the appended matrix with the identity matrix won't match when (N-k) is not equal to one.

Comment: It shows up again in $(B.2)$ but as $0$ instead of $O$.